# Матрица для параллельных вычислений

Tags: матрицы, mpi

Реализовал алгоритм для решения системы линейных уравнений в среде MPI. Уравнения вида `Ax = b`. Не могу найти большую матрицу, желательно квадратную с вектором правой стороны. Т.е, например:

```
2 4 5 6            5
3 4 1 5  и вектор  2
1 9 8 3            3 
8 3 2 5
```

Нашёл данный ресурс: https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/,
но не понимаю как можно переформатировать в нужный мне формат, кто сталкивался буду очень признателен за датасет или растолкование как переформатировать.

Answer (score 1):

http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/searchtool.html - вот вам целый MatrixMarket - индустриальный стандарт по тестовым матрицам